# Yii2: What is the correct way to include the grid-view widget in form file

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I have this code in my _form.php. The problem I am facing is if I am putting the pagination part below it does work, but filter doesn't work. If I am putting the filter part below the pagination part, the filter part work and pagination doesn't work.

Again my netbeans IDE is complaining that I have declared the `$dataprovider` twice.

here is my code.
**Form part:**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\State;
use app\models\StateSearch;
use app\models\City;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\State */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
<div class="state-form">

   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?> 

    <?= $form->field($model, 'state_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**Pagination part**

```
<?php
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => State::find(),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

**Filter part**

```
<?php  
   $searchModel = New StateSearch(); 
   $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
   ?>
```

**Gridview Widget**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           // 'id',
            'state_name',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>   
</div>
</div>
```

1. What is the correct approach that my filter and pagination both works.
2. How to show action column icons inline(that is horizontally), I can do it at view level by setting the width, but thinking if there is a global setting for that.
3. Can provide the pagination option on the grid-view for user selection like 5,10 or all.

Thanks.

Comment: never mind, last time I tried to help you I did not even get a vote up.